# Laravel Streaming Results Lazily

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to reproduce pretty simple snippet from
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#streaming-results-lazily

```
use App\Models\Flight;

foreach (Flight::lazy() as $flight) {
    //
}
```

But I get `Call to undefined method App\Models\Flight::lazy()` error and I just can't figure why. Thanks for advice.

Comment: which laravel version.check composer file for exact version laravel/framework

Comment: You're probably looking for `foreach(Flight::cursor() as $flight)`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#cursors. Also, ensure you're using Laravel 8; `lazy()` was introduced in `8.x` and is not available in previous versions.

Comment: @TimLewis cursor cannot eager load relationships, so its not what I'm looking for.

Comment: While that's a fair point, your question as written has nothing to do with eager loading of relationships; `Flight::lazy()` doesn't do eager loading of relationships, and isn't available, so I linked the best available function for your Laravel version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `lazy()` method added in laravel version `v8.34.0`.Even if you are using `Laravel 8` then make sure it should be at least version `v8.34.0`

As per Laravel Framework release note.

```
Added lazy() and lazyById() methods to Illuminate\Database\Concerns\BuildsQueries
```

Ref:https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.34.0
Ref:https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/36699

[image]

Comment: Currently my version is 8.20.1, so you are right. Thanks :)